# grunt-contrib-watch not seeing new files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I wanted to post here before resurrecting bugs from the dead on their github, is there anything malformed with my files section?

**The Watch section is as follows:**

```
watch: {
    files: ['includes/js/source/_*.js'],
    tasks: 'dev',
},
```

a `grunt --verbose` gives me the following:

```
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Watching includes/js/source/_broken.js for changes.
Watching includes/js/source/_hi.js for changes.
Watching includes/js/source/_jquery_ui_1.10.3_autocomplete.js for changes.
Watching includes/js/source/_menu_toggle.js for changes.
Watching includes/js/source/_thisisatest.js for changes.
Watching includes/js/source for changes.
```

**System Specs:**
Mac osx 10.9.3 with Vagrant running:
Ubuntu 12.04 (php 5.5.11, apache 2.4.9)
node v0.10.28
npm 1.4.9
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5

**Running just the `dev` task appears to be working as expected**

```
/var/www/themissingsearch $ grunt dev -v
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "GruntFile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Registering "grunt-contrib-uglify" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Parsing /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify/package.json...OK
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...OK
+ uglify

Registering "grunt-contrib-concat" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Parsing /var/www/themissingsearch/node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat/package.json...OK
Loading "concat.js" tasks...OK
+ concat
Loading "GruntFile.js" tasks...OK
+ default, dev, production

Running tasks: dev

Running "dev" task

Running "concat" task

Running "concat:build" (concat) task
Verifying property concat.build exists in config...OK
Files: includes/js/source/_jquery_ui_1.10.3_autocomplete.js, includes/js/source/_menu_toggle.js, includes/js/source/hellllo.js, includes/js/source/hi.js, includes/js/source/hi2.js, includes/js/source/thisisanewfile.js -> includes/js/themissingsearch.0.1.0.dev.min.js
Options: separator="\n", banner="/*! themissingsearch 06-11-2014 1:36:31 am */\n\n", footer="", stripBanners=false, process=undefined
Reading includes/js/source/_jquery_ui_1.10.3_autocomplete.js...OK
Reading includes/js/source/_menu_toggle.js...OK
Reading includes/js/source/hellllo.js...OK
Reading includes/js/source/hi.js...OK
Reading includes/js/source/hi2.js...OK
Reading includes/js/source/thisisanewfile.js...OK
Writing includes/js/themissingsearch.0.1.0.dev.min.js...OK
File includes/js/themissingsearch.0.1.0.dev.min.js created.

Done, without errors.
```

Comment: It seems to be fine. Check `dev` task also. May be `watch` works properly, but something in `dev` fails to run, so you don't see any feedback. However, this should not be the case, as `watch` will notify you that watched files have changed.

Comment: `dev` appears to be working fine, with a couple small tests all code compiles, even new files.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue within Vagrant not Grunt.

The fix was to uninstall Node & npm on my vagrant box and installed everything on my mac proper.